# YII2: submit form using AJAX and return success message

Tags: php, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

I am rendering contact us form in another view with the following code.

```
<?php echo $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $contactModel,
            ]); ?>
```

I also included

```
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
```

to the form header.
My controller code is like the following.

```
$model = new ContactForm();

        $data = "";
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                $data = "success";
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending email.');
                $data = "Error";
            }

        }else{
            $data = false;
        }

        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return $data;
```

When I am trying to submit the form the validation works perfectly but when all the fields are entered correctly the page reloads with ajax request showing twice in firebug console. I want the page to stay on the form and fetch and display the success or error message from the controller.

Comment: You should provide your client side code.